# Согласовать анимацию нескольких элементов

Tags: c#, wpf

Существует необходимость переводить `UserControl` в мигающее состояние. Сначала мигает один, потом вместе с ним начинают мигать и остальные (мигать должны все одновременно).

В данный момент `UserControl` содержит вот такой метод:

```
private void LaunchAnimation()
{
    var blinkAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    blinkAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(1, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0))));
    blinkAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))));

    var blinkStoryboard = new Storyboard
    {
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(SettingsMaster.AnimationFrameDuration), RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,               
    };

    Storyboard.SetTarget(blinkAnimation, this.Control);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(blinkAnimation, new PropertyPath(Canvas.OpacityProperty));

    blinkStoryboard.Children.Add(blinkAnimation);
    blinkStoryboard.Begin();

}
```

Но в этом случае анимация разных элементов не согласована и они мигают вразнобой. Проблема в том, что когда их много (может быть 100 и более), это смотрится очень вырвиглазно. Как заставить их мигать синхронно? Возможно ли как-то реализовать контейнер, при помещении в который к ним бы применялась общая анимация?

Comment: контролы можно привязать к какому-то свойству. с помощью дата-тригера. а анимацию применять к этому свойству.